# Use a formula written in another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've got three different calculations compiled in cells A1, A2 and A3.

> A1: ([@Quantity]×[DUC])-[@Invoiced] 
> A2: (([@Quantity]×[@DUC])-[@Invoiced])+((([@Quantity]×[@DUC]])-[@Invoiced])×(([@VAT])/100)×(([@[% of VAT to expense]])/100)) 
> A3: (([@Line]-(([@Line]×(1-(100/(100+[@VAT])))))/[@Quantity])-[@Invoiced])+((([@Line]-(([@Line]×(1-(100/(100+[@VAT])))))/[@Quantity])-[@Invoiced])×(([@VAT])/100)*(([@[% of VAT to expense]])/100))

I have data in a separate table, with a column Calculation which determines which of the three formulae should be used for that particular line. It returns `A1`, `A2` or `A3`.

What I need to do is to run the linked calculation for that table line, based on the @Calculation column.

I have tried: 
`=INDIRECT("="&[@Calculation])` which returns `#REF!`
`="="&INDIRECT([@Calculation])` which returns (if the Calculation returned was `A1`) `=([@Quantity]×[@DUC])-[@Invoiced]`
`="="&[@Calculation]` which returns `=A1`
`=[@Calculation]` which returns `A1`

But I need the calculation to be run, not just returning it as text.

This should be a simple thing to do. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

## **EDIT**

I can't use a nested `IF` or `IFS` in the table itself, because (as you can see in A3), the formula would be enormous. I'm limited to a formula not exceeding 255 characters.

Comment: So, instead of returning A1, A2 or A3, put the functions in the calculation. like: =if(A1=1000,A1_calculation) etc

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood, @SolarMike, the calculation would look like ```=IF([@Calculation]="A1",([@Quantity]×[DUC])-[@Invoiced],IF([@Calculation="A2",...```
If I've got this correct, this isn't an option. I can't nest all possible calculations as the entire calculation would be too long; I'm limited to 255 characters for any one formula.

Comment: That's why I wanted to list all possible calculations elsewhere and reference them from the table.

Comment: Then have the results for all options calculated and select the correct one by using vlookup().

Comment: Why are  you limited to 255 characters?

Comment: @Rory - I'm extracting table/data via a Jet Report (SQL) and the Excel-formula is recognised as text, so is limited to 255 characters by Excel.

Comment: @SolarMike's solution is not likely to work as A3 formula (when written out in full) exceeds 255 characters by itself. Even if it was do-able (if the calculations were broken up, it could work), the returned report would look very messy, providing a Calculation1, Calculation2, Calculation3a and Calculation3b, and a final column to show what the correct answer is.

Comment: @marc then you should consider how to reduce your calculation length or look at the other idea I gave you, perhaps think about how to get rid of some of those parentheses...

Comment: You could reduce formula length by creating intermediate calculations in the table, then use the intermediate calculations in the formula, e.g., `[@Quantity]×[DUC]` becomes `[@QtyXDuc]`.

Comment: You mean the formula is stored in a back end table? If so, why? Also, is there a reason for not using power query?

Comment: @Rory - my financial database is stored outside of Excel. I'm using Jet/SQL to extract certain fields/tables into a useable Excel Table. One of the columns of that Excel Table will one of three calculations. The calculations are too large to embed into the Excel Table by default (a user would need to enter the calculation, and I don't trust users to be able to do that). So I'm trying to find a way for Excel to choose the calculation (via the Calculation column) and then perform that calculation (with the formulae written elsewhere on the sheet.

Comment: @bugdrown, @solarmike: I can look to reduce the formula length, so that [@Quantity] becomes [@Qty] for example, but as Excel sees the insides of the ```[]``` as a column name, I need to make sure that the abbreviated column names continue to make sense. But the corrected formula would become ```([@Qty]*[@DUC])-[@[Inv Ex.VAT]]```. Shaving  few characters off will help, but the total nested formula is over 600 characters. I'm not sure all columns will be wholly meaningful.

Comment: I'm currently looking at ```EVALUATE()``` as a named range [link](https://superuser.com/questions/253353/excel-function-that-evaluates-a-string-as-if-it-were-a-formula) but I'm not sure this works in a Table. I wonder if ```LAMDA()``` might work instead...

Comment: @Marc `LAMBDA()` is still only for insiders but `LET()` is available on O365.

Comment: @Marc Could you use a UDF, using `SELECT CASE` with the calculation, e.g., `A3` as a function parameter? Or, as you're considering, `EVALUATE`?

Comment: Thanks @bugdrown. It took me a while to work out why LAMBDA was working until I read it was just for the privileged few. I don't even know if it would work for other users - if I did have LAMBDA, but another user (who didn't) used the sheet, would it work for them? Anyway, I abandoned that idea after a while.

Comment: I also got rid of ```EVALUATE``` - it worked, but I couldn't find a formula to populate the cell reference, and if the sheet had to be saved as a macro file anyway, I'd be better off using UDF. Anyway, I abandoned this idea, too.

Comment: I settled for ```LET``` in the end, but I'm not happy with that solution. Again, the ```LET``` formula is limited to 255 characters, and the actual formula I was using (substituting the field names for letters) was 173 characters, so I ended up really reducing the name of the fields, for example ```[@[Invoiced Received (Ex. VAT)]]``` was reduced to ```[@Inv£]```. But this is what I was hoping to avoid when @SolarMike mentioned it.

Comment: Anyway, thank you to everyone who chipped in on this. I suspect ```LAMBDA``` will be the ideal solution (if/when it's released) ... unless JET changes it's structure to allow for longer formulae...?